# How to install file into folder in system drive

Tags: installshield

For example, install file 1.txt into c:\my

I have created property named CM in property table, and set value to c:\my, what should I do next?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Files and Folders section under Application data in Installation Designer. Click on the Destination folder and create predefined or your own custom folder here. Once done, do the right click on right window and add the desired file.

Comment: after creating folder, go to properties page of the folder to take a look the directory identifier, then open property table to new a property whose name is same with directory identifier, then set the value. The value is where file in the directory I created is installed into. works.